# effective way to cache about 8 million records in java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web

I have a web application in java, i have to cache about 8 million records to minimize connection request to database(MySql). What would be the effective solution to handle this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that B follows logically from A

Comment: Why? Every cache introduces cache-coherency problems. Application-side caches more so, as the required mechanisms are either absent or poorly understood by applications programmers. Every time I've seen an application-side cache it has been a source of problems, and in most cases not worth the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you don't have memory issues to store 80lac records. You can create two maps. In first map(let's call it RECORDS), you store all the records using a key-value pair mechanism. Create a second map(let's call it a CACHED_RECORD). Implement a MRU algorithm to store entries in CACHED_RECORD. Implement get logic of record in such a fashion:

- Query record from CACHED_MAP.
- If record is found, return the record from CACHED_MAP.
- If the record is not present, get the record from RECORDS, and update the entry in CACHED_RECORD using MRU logic.

For MRU logic, you can refer - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies

Another approach would be to index your records based on certain rules/policies(ex: people's name starting with A in a certain region).

Although, it's not a good approach to store 80lac records. You should benchmark your application's performance too.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

So, the best simple practice is to get records and hold it in the map(for ex.)
and if map doesn't contains any records, get it from DB.
It will look like

```
private List<Records> cachedRecords;

public List<Record> getRecords()
{
   if (cachedRecords == null)
   cachedRecords = DB.getConnection().getRecords();
}

return cachedRecords;
```

Update: Also you can use Hibernate, where exists instruments like lazy initialization

Comment: Is there any way to make caching faster?